# Finding similar trips in a database

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a `trips` table and a `bus_stops` table. The `trips` table has a `from_stop_id` and a `to_stop_id`. The `bus_stops` table has `lat` and `lng` information for each bus stop.

How can I order the trips in descending order of popularity, where popularity is defined as the number of other trips in the database that start and end within a particular distance of the given trip? For the moment, I am happy to work with 'as the crow flies' distance between two points.

Neither of the tables is spatial but I am using Postgres and adding PostGIS extension is also possible, so if that's the best way forward then I'd love to hear it.

thanks a million

Comment: Before attempting an answer, can you clarify two questions: Is either of the tables spatial? i.e. do they have a 'the_geom' column in PostGIS? And second, to calculate popularity  as number of other trips that start/end within a certain distance, is this a straight line distance "as the crow files" or distance along some street network?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach. First get PostGIS installed. There's plenty of explanations how to do that such as [postgis.net installation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html):

Now make your bus_stops table spatial:

```
-- Assuming the Lng/Lat are WGS84 coordinates 
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('bus_stops','geom',4326,'POINT',2); 

UPDATE bus_stops SET geom=ST_MakePoint(lng, lat);

-- Here's a query that returns the distances for each trip 
-- between the "from' bus_stop and the "from" stop of all the other trips 

SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(bs1.geom, bs2.geom), t.t_id  
FROM trips AS t, bus_stops AS bs1, bus_stops AS bs2  
WHERE ( t.from_bs_id=bs1.bs_id AND t.from_bs_id <> bs2.bs_id );  

-- And similarly, the distances between the "to" bus stops 

SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(bs1.geom, bs2.geom), t.t_id  
FROM trips AS t, bus_stops AS bs1, bus_stops AS bs2  
WHERE (t.to_bs_id=bs1.bs_id AND t.to_bs_id<>bs2.bs_id);

-- To count how many trips have "from" stops within a certain minimum:
-- (The numbers are from some fictitious tables)
-- (I choose 3000 m. as a sample. Set to whatever is needed...)  

SELECT t.t_id AS TripID, count(t.t_id) As Cnt_Close 
FROM trips AS t, bus_stops AS bs1, bus_stops AS bs2 
WHERE (t.to_bs_id=bs1.bs_id AND 
    t.to_bs_id<>bs2.bs_id) AND 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(bs1.geom, bs2.geom) < 3000 
GROUP BY TripID ORDER BY Cnt_Close; 
tripid | cnt_close 
            --------+-----------
                  8 |         1
                 11 |         1
                  9 |         1
                 13 |         2
                  7 |         2
                 12 |         2
                 10 |         2
                  5 |         2
                  4 |         2
                  6 |         3
                  1 |         3
                 14 |         3
                  2 |         5
                  3 |         5
            (14 rows)
```

So we're getting close... Next we merge into the query both the distances of the "from" stops and the distances to the "to" stops:

```
SELECT t.t_id AS TripID, count(t.t_id) As Cnt_Close 
FROM trips AS t, bus_stops AS bs1, bus_stops AS bs2, bus_stops AS bs3, bus_stops AS bs4 
WHERE (t.to_bs_id=bs1.bs_id AND t.to_bs_id<>bs2.bs_id) AND 
    (t.from_bs_id=bs3.bs_id AND t.from_bs_id<>bs4.bs_id) AND 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(bs1.geom, bs2.geom) < 2000 AND 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(bs3.geom, bs4.geom) < 2000 
GROUP BY TripID ORDER BY Cnt_Close;
     tripid | cnt_close 
    --------+-----------
          5 |         2
          8 |         2
          9 |         2
          1 |         2
         11 |         2
          2 |         2
         13 |         3
          3 |         3
          7 |         4
          6 |         4
         10 |         4
         14 |         6
    (12 rows)
```

Now we're ready to setup the popularity. First add a column to hold the value:

```
ALTER TABLE trips ADD COLUMN popularity INTEGER;
-- Now the update using the above subquery

UPDATE trips SET popularity=(
SELECT count(t.t_id) 
FROM trips AS t, bus_stops AS bs1, bus_stops AS bs2, bus_stops AS bs3, bus_stops AS bs4 
WHERE (t.to_bs_id=bs1.bs_id AND t.to_bs_id<>bs2.bs_id) AND 
    (t.from_bs_id=bs3.bs_id AND t.from_bs_id<>bs4.bs_id) AND 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(bs1.geom, bs2.geom) < 2000 AND 
    ST_Distance_Sphere(bs3.geom, bs4.geom) < 2000 AND 
    t.t_id=trips.t_id
);
UPDATE 14
```

**Whew...**

Comment: wow! thanks so much! I'm going to try it out. Will report back with my results. thanks